# The number of daily visitors to a website decreased 9% last month to 3003 people. How many daily visitors were there before the decrease

Tags: percentages

The number of daily visitors to a website decreased 9% last month to 3003. How many daily visitors were there before the site decrease

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $X\times0.91=3003$

Comment: I'm especially interested in solutions to this problem that use the fact that $3003=\binom{15}{5}$.

Comment: @AndrewOstergaard:  $\dfrac{15!}{5!10!}=7\times13\times3\times11$; divide that by $\dfrac{7\times13}{100}$ to get the answer $3\times11\times100$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Awesome! Now I'm trying to think if there's any combinatorial significance to the fact that $1-\dfrac{9}{100}=\dfrac{14\cdot13}{200}$, because if there is, then we could use your idea to make an even more combinatorial solution! Unfortunately I can't think of any just yet. In any event, thanks for your idea!

Answer (score 3):

You simply have to solve the equation:

$x\cdot\left(1-\frac9{100}\right)=3003$